# Allow AJAX Through Devise (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I've just added and configured the devise gem. It's working great except for blocking my form's autosave AJAX calls.

At the top of my controller, I have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

My AJAX call comes to the same controller:

```
  def autosave
    #TODO: update relative entry
    #TODO: verify user logged in
    #TODO: verify entry belongs to relative user
    render content_type: 'text/xml', inline: "<result status='ok' />"
  end
```

Of course I could instead declare my before filter like so:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :autosave
```

..but this offers nothing to prevent anyone from calling this controller function at any time.

What would be the best way to allow this function to be called? I still want to ensure that only logged in users can make the call and that the given record they're editing belongs to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you just need to add a bit of logic to your autosave. With this setup the function will still be called per se, but whether or not it does anything is a another mater entirely unless the conditions are right.

```
def autosave
  #Verify that the user is signed in and he has ownership of entry
  if !current_user.nil? && entry.user == current_user
    render content_type: 'text/xml', inline: "<result status='ok' />"
  else
    #do nothing nothing or redirect with error here
  end  
end
```

Since you're making an AJAX post you have to provide some additional information to your ajax call as a security countermeasure, namely a CSRF security token. See  [Devise not setting current_user on Ajax post even though correct x-csrf-token is included in request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393871/devise-not-setting-current-user-on-ajax-post-even-though-correct-x-csrf-token-is) for an example AJAX request using a security token. Also, make sure you also include `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in your head tag.

Comment: Since the call is coming from AJAX (a CKEDITOR form to be exact) and not from a Rails link, it looks like current_user.nil? will always return true.

Is there a specific parameter I have to pass?

Comment: What exactly does current_user return?