# ajax call causes internal server error 500 rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, internal-server-error

I use ruby on rails mvc and I'm trying to use an ajax call to send some data back to the server side. I'm confused about how ajax requests are issued and processed in the mvc.

---------------- in my javascript file------------------

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/locations',
    data: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
```

});

I'm using a respond_to block to catch this request in my controller:

---------------- in my home controller ------------------

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { 
      render 'users/locations' 
    }
    format.html {} 
end
```

---------------- route.rb ------------------------

```
post 'users/locations'
get 'users/locations'
match "/locations", to: "users#locations"
```

I tried to extract the data this way:

---------------- in my locations action------------------

```
dasdasdd // used as a breakpoint to test whether this part was executed. it wasn't.
current_user.update_attribute :Latitude, params[:lat]
current_user.update_attribute :Longitude, params[:lng]
```

With the debugging firefox console, I see a internal servers error 500. This might explain why the locations action was never executed. But why is there an error 500? Can anybody shine some light into how I might be wrong?

Comment: You can find plenty of information in the `app/development.log` as well as in the response body of the `500` error regarding the exception. We'd just be guessing what your problem is without knowing *what* the Exception being thrown is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dataType you have specified in your ajax call is json, try

```
format.json { 
      render 'users/locations' 
    }
```

instead of format.js in your controller

Comment: Thank you so much, but I've solved the mystery. It's the problem with a devise authentication module that I use. When that module fails in the locations action, a method doesn't work, which leads to the 500 internal server error. The ajax post apparently needs a csrf headerfor authentication purposes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393871/devise-not-setting-current-user-on-ajax-post-even-though-correct-x-csrf-token-is